# How to test a function only defined in CPP file with GoogleTest

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I'm new with GoogleTest framework and I have an issue related to testing utility methods that are only defined in the CPP file. In the following example I would like to test the function `baz` without exposing it through the `.hpp` file. What would be the best approach?

```
// .hpp
namespace ns {
  void foo();
  void bar();
}


// .cpp
#include ".hpp"

void baz() {
}

namespace ns {
  void foo() {
    baz();
  }

  void bar() {
    baz();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to expose `baz` through the .hpp file. You can declare `void baz();` in any file before its usage. Even inside a function, like

```
void foobar() {
  void baz();
  baz();
}
```